# Finding the area bounded by two curves

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

> Find the area of the region bounded by the parabola $y = 4x^2$, the tangent line to this parabola at $(2, 16)$, and the $x$-axis.

I found the tangent line to be $y=16x-16$ and set up the integral from $0$ to $2$ of $4x^2-16x+16$ with respect to $x$, which is the top function when looking at the graph minus the bottom function. I took the integral and came up with $\frac{4}{3}x^3-8x^2+16x$ evaluated between $0$ and $2$. This came out to be $\frac{32}{3}$ but this was the incorrect answer. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The tangent crosses the $x$ axis at $x=1$, so your integral is including (with the plus sign) also the triangle made by the tangent below the $x$ axis.
The correct way is to integrate only the parabola for $x=0 \cdots 2$ (which is $32/3$ and then subtract the area of the triangle$(1,0),(2,16),(2,0)$, which is $8$, so the net area is $8/3$ .

Answer (score 0):

It isn't right. Try to draw such region.

**Hint:** After drawing it, note that you have to calculate $\int_0^1 4x^2\;dx + \int_1^2 4x^2-16x+16\;dx$.

Comment: I did this and got 12, but this was still incorrect. Any suggestions?

Comment: I got $\frac{8}{3}$. I'm sorry but did you do it right?

Comment: Oh I see what I did. I now got 8/3 as well. Thanks!

Comment: Any time! ${}{}$